# How to recursively replace \n\r with \n in all php files

Tags: shell, command-line, centos

Is there a command line way of iterating recursively over a directory and changing all \n\r to \n in all PHP files?

I am using CentOS.

Comment: why do you want to do so? recommend to use `PHP_EOL` instead !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a command line, but a easier macro command can be installed on your machine: dos2unix

see http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_dos2uni.htm